# Proper way of flattening array from MySQL in a single object

Tags: mysql, node.js

From DB I receive result set, as an Array with one object inside it. There is always going to be one object, as I control the queries.

I do not have any ORM (like this [list](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-comparison-of-the-top-orms-for-2018-19c4feeaa5f)), nor do I plan to add one, since the code is run on Lambda, and I will not have many queries to warrant adding ORM on top of it. I will have several READ queries and thats it.

Currently, I have several approaches how to do just that.

```
const result = await MySQLQueryBuilder.getMyQueryObject(userId);
  const resultSet = result[0];
```

This clearly introduces intermediate variable

```
let result = await MySQLQueryBuilder.getMyQueryObject(userId);
  result = result[0];
```

And this one looks a bit weird.

Ideally I would do something on query level to make it return only single object.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put limit 1 on your query and make changes from main file like this.

```
let [result] = await MySQLQueryBuilder.getMyQueryObject(userId);
console.log(result);
```